# How to concatenate multiple json columns in panda

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have a df with the following format:

```
id json_1 json_2 json_3 
1  {a:b}  {a:c}  {c:d}
2  {a:b}  {b:c}  null
3  {a:c}  {c:d}  {a:g}
```

I want to create a new column which concatenates (i.e., takes union) json_1, json_2, and json_3 columns.

json_1, json_2, and json_3 are dictionary text.

Desired output:

```
 id json_1 json_2 json_3 final_json
 1  {a:b}  {a:c}  {c:d}   [{a:b}, {a:c}, {c:d}]
 2  {a:b}  {b:c}  null    [{a:b}, {b:c}]
 3  {a:c}  {c:d}  {a:g}   [{a:c}, {c:d}, {a:g}]
```

Comment: hmm, `{{a:b}, {a:c}, {c:d}}` is not valid, need list?

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly, but it seems this should solve your problem `df['final_json'] = df[['json_1', 'json_2', 'json_3']].apply(lambda x: set(x) - set(['null']), axis=1)` (here one is assuming that the dataframe name is `df`). Let me know if that works out

Comment: "json" is not a python nor pandas datatype, what do you *actually* have in each cell? A dictionary, text, or something else?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I revised the question. The input is a dictionary text in each column. The output I need is a json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the type of data and additional requirements, this should do the work

```
df['final_json'] = df[['json_1', 'json_2', 'json_3']].apply(lambda x: set(x) - set(['null']), axis=1)

[Out]:
   id json_1 json_2 json_3             final_json
0   1  {a:b}  {a:c}  {c:d}  {{c:d}, {a:c}, {a:b}}
1   2  {a:b}  {b:c}   null         {{b:c}, {a:b}}
2   3  {a:c}  {c:d}  {a:g}  {{a:g}, {c:d}, {a:c}}
```

As per OP's [new Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/73796490/2), if the goal is just to get that desired output, assuming one is proceeding from the previous operation, then that can be achieved through various methods, such as:

- Using `js.dumps()`

  ```
  import json as js

  df['final_json'] = df['final_json'].apply(lambda x: js.dumps(x))
  ```
- Using `list()`

  ```
  df['final_json'] = df['final_json'].apply(lambda x: list(x))
  ```
- Using `str()`

  ```
  df['final_json'] = df['final_json'].apply(lambda x: str(x))
  ```

They all give the following dataframe

```
   id json_1 json_2 json_3                   final_json
0   1  {a:b}  {a:c}  {c:d}  ["{c:d}", "{a:c}", "{a:b}"]
1   2  {a:b}  {b:c}   null           ["{b:c}", "{a:b}"]
2   3  {a:c}  {c:d}  {a:g}  ["{a:g}", "{c:d}", "{a:c}"]
```

It would be a matter of selecting the approach that better fits OPs use case, noting that there might be other ways to do that.

---

As an alternative, here is a one liner that will give OP the same output as the updated desired output, but by starting from OP's dataframe in the question

```
df['final_json'] = df[['json_1', 'json_2', 'json_3']].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i != 'null'], axis=1)

[Out]:
   id json_1 json_2 json_3             final_json
0   1  {a:b}  {a:c}  {c:d}  [{a:b}, {a:c}, {c:d}]
1   2  {a:b}  {b:c}   null         [{a:b}, {b:c}]
2   3  {a:c}  {c:d}  {a:g}  [{a:c}, {c:d}, {a:g}]
```

If the columns can hold values that are `NaN`, one might consider either the following operation ([or jezrael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73796562/7109869))

```
df['final_json'] = df[['json_1', 'json_2', 'json_3']].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i != 'null' and i != np.nan], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If need filter out missing values and join dictionaries use list comprehension with `pd.notna`:

If need filter columns with `json` substrings:

```
df['final_json'] = df.filter(like='json').apply(lambda x: [y for y in x if pd.notna(y)], axis=1)
```

If need filter columns by list:

```
df['final_json'] = df[['json_1', 'json_2', 'json_3']].apply(lambda x: [y for y in x if pd.notna(y)], axis=1)
```